# Registration form validation issue in BackboneJS

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm new to Backbone, and trying to create a **registration page**. It's done, but with an unresolved issue.

**The issues is**, when i leave some field blank it's showing error, but it's only hiding the errors back when all the fields are entered right. 
For **example**, fill one field, leave 2 empty. It'll show error for empty fields, but when you enter 1 field among the 2, even the right value, then also it's not hiding the error back regarding that field.

```
function IsEmail(email) {

    var regex = /^[A-Za-z]([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}

var Reg = Backbone.Model.extend({

    url: '#',

    defaults: {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''
    },

    validate: function (attrs) {
        var errors = [];

        if (!attrs.name) {
            errors.push({
                name: 'name',
                message: 'Please fill name field.'
            });
        }
        if (!(IsEmail(attrs.email))) {
            errors.push({
                name: 'email',
                message: 'Please fill email field.'
            });
        }
        if (!attrs.password) {
            errors.push({
                name: 'password',
                message: 'Please fill password field.'
            });
        }

        return errors.length > 0 ? errors : false;
    }


});
var RegView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'row',

    template: '\
        <form>\
            <legend>Register Yourself</legend>\
            <div class="control-group name">\
                <label>Username</label>\
                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your name...">\
                <span class="error-inline"></span>\
            </div>\
            <div class="control-group password">\
                <label>Password</label>\
                <input type="text" id="password" placeholder="Your password...">\
                <span class="error-inline"></span>\
            </div>\
            <div class="control-group email">\
                <label>Email</label>\
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Your email address...">\
                <span class="error-inline"></span>\
            </div>\
            <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>\
        </form>\
    ',

    events: {
        'click #submit': 'submitClicked'

    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template);

        return this;
    },

    submitClicked: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var me = this;
        var options = {
            success: function () {
                me.hideErrors();
            },
            error: function (model, errors) {
                me.showErrors(errors);
            }
        };

        var R = {
            name: this.$('#name').val(),
            email: this.$('#email').val(),
            password: this.$('#password').val()
        };

        this.model.save(R, options);
    },

    showErrors: function (errors) {
        _.each(errors, function (error) {
            var controlGroup = this.$('.' + error.name);
            controlGroup.addClass('error');
            controlGroup.find('.error-inline').text(error.message);
        }, this);
    },

    hideErrors: function () {
        this.$('.control-group').removeClass('error');
        this.$('.error-inline').text('');
    }
});
var m = new Reg();
var v = new RegView({
    model: m
});
$(document.body).append(v.render().el);
```

Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coder_raaaz/yE6Z5/).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can add something like `$('.error-inline').html('');` to the beginning of `showErrors()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only clearing your errors on success. You need to clear all errors before validation, as it will add back any errors that still exist.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somethingkindawierd/w6ZDS/). The relevant change is adding `this.hideErrors()` here:

```
submitClicked: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Clear all existing errors now
    this.hideErrors();

    var me = this;
    ...
}
```